# React checkbox false/true switched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have a checkbox in react where the true/false is switched up. I can't get it to properly have the value of the checkbox set.

```
const [checkBoxValue, setCheckBoxValue] = useState<boolean>(false);

...

const checkBoxSet= (e: boolean) => {
  setCheckBoxValue(e);
}

<div>
  <CheckBox type={'checkbox'} checked={checkBoxValue} onChange={(event) => {setCheckBoxValue(event.target.checked)}}/>
          checkbox
</div>
```

Now if the checkbox is checked it is false, if not its true.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event handling code to:

```
setCheckBoxValue(!event.target.checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [checkBoxValue, setCheckBoxValue] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckBoxtype={'checkbox'} checked={checkBoxValue} onChange={(event) => {setCheckBoxValue(!checkBoxValue)}}/> checkbox
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```